# TextView String Java

Tags: java, android

I have a textview, the text inside the textview will change.
So now i want to be able to run some code, but only when certain words are in the textview.

I have an example but for a editText. I tried using this code for a TextView. But i run into some errors. Saying that this can not be used for TextView only for EditText..

Here is the code for the EditText.

```
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                    if ("bottom_green".equalsIgnoreCase(command.getText().toString())) {
                        //Whenever you got user click enter. Get text in edittext and check it equal test1. If it's true do your code in listenerevent of button3
                        blue.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_color_line_line6);

                    }
                }
```

I think my problem is the KeyEvent.  I have the KeyEvent in this code, to execute the code when the enter button is hit.  But with the textview, the user will not be able to edit the text and be able to hit enter.

I tried taking that code out completely for the keyevent and put this code in:

```
if ("rotate".equalsIgnoreCase(text1.getText().toString())) {
```

But this doesn't work either..

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the user won't be able to edit the content of the TextView. So you'll need to identify the part of your code that does change the content and then call from there the method that will check the content of the text view and does whatever needs to be done.

Comment: I have added the code in where it makes the text change. But i still can't figure out how to set it  if the text shows a certain keyword, run this code.  If i just put some code in there now, whatever shows up in the textView it will run the code...

Comment: The last line of code you show in your question ("rotate".equalsIgnoreCase...) is basically how one compares the content of a TextView to a string. Are you saying that condition is always true? You might need to post more code to clarify your question...

Answer (score 0):

May be you can associate a handler and when any key is pressed send a empty message to the handler. Upon receiving the message, the handler can check and change the text!